# rolling square root and other functions

Tags: r

I am tyring to create a series of rolling error functions. I have the following data:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  date <- seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = 1, length.out = 100),
  pred <- sample(1000, 100, replace = FALSE),
  actual <- sample(1000, 100, replace = FALSE)
) %>% 
  setNames(c("date", "pred", "actual"))
```

Which looks like:

```
          date pred actual
1   2010-01-01   99    835
2   2010-01-02  429    779
3   2010-01-03  726    581
```

I want to use the `rollapply` function to create rolling squared errors. I can use the following to create rolling means

```
window_size = 30 + 1 -1
dat %>%
  arrange(desc(date)) %>%
  mutate(
    error = (pred - actual),
    squared_error = error**2,

    #rolling calcs
    rolling_mean_error = c(rollapply(error, width = window_size, by = 1, FUN = mean), rep(NA, window_size - 1))
  )
```

However, I would like to use a `squared_error` functon.

```
squared_function <- function(err){
  err**2
}


dat %>%
  arrange(desc(date)) %>%
  mutate(
    error = (pred - actual),
    squared_error = error**2,

    #rolling calcs
    rolling_mean_error = c(rollapply(error, width = window_size, by = 1, FUN = mean), rep(NA, window_size - 1)),
    rolling_squared_error = c(rollapply(error, width = window_size, by = 1, FUN = squared_function), rep(NA, window_size - 1))
  )
```

However, it fails with the following error:

> Error: `mutate()` argument `rolling_squared_error` must be recyclable.
>   ℹ `rolling_squared_error` is `c(...)`. x `rolling_squared_error` can't
>   be recycled to size 100. ℹ `rolling_squared_error` must be size 100 or
>   1, not 2159

EDIT:

Libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
```

Comment: (1) `data.frame(date <- ...)` is a bad idea, you should really use `=` instead of `<-` here. (2) Please set your random seed (e.g., `set.seed(42)`) immediately before that and repost your numbers, we are very unlikely to be able to reproduce your numbers.

Comment: I have added the libraries. Thanks for letting me know that I should use `=` here. I was curious why the column names were strange.

Comment: (3) `zoo::rollapply(..., align="left", fill=NA)` will mitigate your need to do `c(..., rep(NA, window-1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `squared_function` should return a single number, not a vector the same length as the input. I suspect you need `sum(err**2)` (sum of squares) or `sqrt(sum(err**2))`.

Try this:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- tibble(
  date   = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), by = 1, length.out = 100),
  pred   = sample(1000, 100, replace = FALSE),
  actual = sample(1000, 100, replace = FALSE)
) %>% 
  setNames(c("date", "pred", "actual"))

window_size <- 30 + 1 -1

squared_function <- function(err) sum(err**2)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  arrange(desc(date)) %>%
  mutate(
    error = (pred - actual),
    squared_error = error**2,
    rolling_mean_error = zoo::rollapply(
      error, width = window_size, by = 1, FUN = mean,
      align = "left", fill = NA),
    rolling_squared_error = zoo::rollapply(
      error, width = window_size, by = 1, FUN = squared_function,
      align = "left", fill = NA)
  )
dat2
# # A tibble: 100 x 7
#    date        pred actual error squared_error rolling_mean_error rolling_squared_error
#    <date>     <int>  <int> <int>         <dbl>              <dbl>                 <dbl>
#  1 2010-04-10   558    659  -101         10201              -93.7               5334540
#  2 2010-04-09   672    671     1             1              -88.6               5326839
#  3 2010-04-08   466    102   364        132496              -70.7               5616282
#  4 2010-04-07   302    481  -179         32041              -67.0               5711315
#  5 2010-04-06   665     49   616        379456              -66.6               5707835
#  6 2010-04-05   839     66   773        597529              -86.8               5328479
#  7 2010-04-04   954    908    46          2116             -103.                4817975
#  8 2010-04-03   190    118    72          5184              -92.8               4935575
#  9 2010-04-02     1    713  -712        506944              -90.2               4952295
# 10 2010-04-01   608    944  -336        112896              -53.0               4610187
# # ... with 90 more rows
```

---

Explanation of `align="left"`.

Each time `squared_function` is called, it is given 30 numbers and needs to return 1. One question: where is that single number placed?

Let's look at a contrived example:

```r
vec <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)
zoo::rollapply(vec, 5, FUN = mean)
#  [1] 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 3 4 5 6 7 6
```

The result is 16 long. When we need it to be the same length as the original vector, we can use `fill=NA` to pad it out to the same length. But that begs the question: where does each number go?

```r
zoo::rollapply(vec, 5, FUN = mean, fill = NA)
#  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  0
# `------. ,--------'
#         v
# __, __, __, __, __
#  3,                 align="left"
# NA, NA,  3          align="right"
# NA, NA, NA, NA,  3  align="right"
```

Comment: Thanks! works perfect. What does the `align = "left"` actually do here?

Comment: (The help page talks about this.) When we sum the square and come up with a single number out of 30, "left" will place the single number in the index on the left of the window, "right" will go on the right side of the mirror, etc. Try it with `align="center"` and note that you now have 14 `NA`s at the start and 15 `NA`s at the end, instead of all 30 at the end.

Comment: @user113156, see my edit for a brief explanation of `align=`.